# Adding inline images to Mailgun emails using Scala and Play WS

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, mailgun

I can succesfully make POST requests to Mailgun and receive the emails as expected.  I'm trying to inline an image into an email and can't work out how to do it.

Looking at https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-api and selecting Java, I can see that the example given constructs a `FileDataBodyPart` with `"inline"`, the `File` reference and the MediaType.  Looking at the curl example, this seems rather unnecessary as that just references a file.

Here is my method for sending an email:

```
  def send(message:EmailMessage) = {
    val postMessage = Map("from" -> Seq(message.from), "to" -> Seq(message.to), "subject" -> Seq(message.subject), "text" -> Seq(message.text), "html" -> Seq(message.html.toString()))
    val logo = FileBody(Play.getExistingFile("/public/images/logo.png").get)
    WS.url(apiUrl).withAuth("api", myKey, WSAuthScheme.BASIC).withBody(logo).post(postMessage)
  }
```

The `message.html.toString` looks like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body style="background-color:#9B59B6; padding:10px">
    <img src="cid:logo.png">
    <h1 style="color:#FFF">Activate!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The logo.png file is found when sending the email and the email comes through fine, but with no image.  This is what the email source looks like once it arrives at gmail:

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#9B59B6; padding:10px">
        <img src="cid:logo.png">
        <h1 style="color:#FFF">Activate!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't see any base64 encoding of the image in the email.  As the curl example appeared to just be passing a file as part of the POST, I though I'd try that.  Here is what I did:

```
  def send(message:EmailMessage) = {

    val logoFile = Play.getExistingFile("/public/images/logo.png").get
    val source = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(logoFile.getAbsolutePath))
    val logoBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(source)

    val postMessage = Map("from" -> Seq(message.from), "to" -> Seq(message.to), "subject" -> Seq(message.subject), "text" -> Seq(message.text), "html" -> Seq(message.html.toString()), "inline" -> Seq(logoBase64))
    WS.url("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/sandboxaa9afcea1f2e4d5db5e2c080f7784b74.mailgun.org/messages").withAuth("api", "key-f165695d4c72e929ff8215115e648c95", WSAuthScheme.BASIC).post(postMessage)
  }
```

I converted the logo into base64 and POSTed that like the other parameters.  Still no joy.

What am I missing here?  Do I need to pass this in the body, but somehow specify that this is an "inline" file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using Jersey, as suggested in the section on libraries:  https://documentation.mailgun.com/libraries.html#java

I imported Jersey in sbt using the following:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-core" % "1.18.3"

libraryDependencies += "com.sun.jersey" % "jersey-client" % "1.18.3"

libraryDependencies += "com.sun.jersey.contribs" % "jersey-multipart" % "1.18.3"
```

and then created my Email sending object like so:

```
object Email {

  val client = Client.create()
  client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("api", current.configuration.getString("mailgun.api.key").get))
  val webResource = client.resource(current.configuration.getString("mailgun.api.url").get)

  def send(message:EmailMessage) = {
    val form = new FormDataMultiPart
    form.field("from", message.from)
    form.field("to", message.to)
    form.field("subject", message.subject)
    form.field("text", message.text)
    form.field("html", message.html.toString())
    val logo = Play.getExistingFile("/public/images/logo.png").get
    form.bodyPart(new FileDataBodyPart("inline", logo, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE))

    webResource.`type`(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).post(form)
  }
}
```

I hope this helps someone.